# Resources reference issue

Tags: c#, object, resources

I obtained a sample code in which it has a Resources folder under the projects, and it was able to use the folder as an object directly.

[image]
[image]

But when I create my own project, even though I was able to create the resources folder, I was NOT able to use it directly! Instead I was referenced to the resource file I created!

[image]
[image]

And I was NOT able to find any declarations of the folder as an object in anywhere in the sample project! And the funny thing is, it doesn't have resx files! I was like it could use the folder magically!!!

And I did a lot of researches in Google, but all I can find is how to create to resource file. That's how I learned how to create it. But I can't find anything telling me why it could be used directly as an object!

Thank you very very much for your help!!!

Comment: When you mark the file in the Solution Explorer and look at the properties, is the Build Action set to "Embedded resource"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! You have to create the folder first and then create the resource resx "INSIDE" the folder!!! Then you could use the folder as an object! Sorry for wasting y'all's time!!!